# Converting STL container<T *> to container<T const *>

Tags: c++, stl

I'm looking for a way to formulate a class having:

- an interface using STL containers of pointers with maximum 'constness'
- but which internally mutates the pointed-to objects
- with no extra run-time overhead compared to a non-const analog

Ideally, the solution would compile to no extra code compared to the non-const version since const/non-const-ness is just an aid to programmers here.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
typedef int T;

class C
{
public:
    // Elements pointed to are mutable, list is not, 'this' is not - compiles OK
    list<T *> const & get_t_list() const { return t_list_; }

    // Neither elements nor list nor' this' are mutable - doesn't compile
    list<T const *> const & get_t_list2() const { return t_list_; }

    // Sanity check: T const * is the problem - doesn't compile
    list<T const *> & get_t_list3() { return t_list_; }

    // Elements pointed to are immutable, 'this' and this->t_list_ are
    // also immutable - Compiles OK, but actually burns some CPU cycles
    list<T const *> get_t_list4() const {
        return list<T const *>( t_list_.begin() , t_list_.end() );
    }

private:
    list<T *> t_list_;
};
```

If there is no solution to the type conversion, I'd like alternative suggestions on how to formulate a class having the properties described.

Comment: `T const` isn't just simply convertible to `T`, you have to use `const_cast`, but that is ugly and violates the point of `const.

Comment: @Tony I want to convert `T` to `T const` though, which is normally possible.  The following compiles: `int x = 2; int const * x_ptr = &x;`

Comment: Different template specializations are unrelated, they're effectively different types.

Comment: @Xeo I understand that's why it doesn't work, but do you have a suggestion on how to formulate a class with an interface that has the properties I want?

Comment: Don't provide direct access to the list, provide iterators / ranges. If you want to be able to mutate the list itself too, make your class *be* a container.

Comment: @Xeo I was hoping to get away with not writing any code!  Care to give an example of what the solution you propose would look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us assume for a moment you can convert `list<T*>&` to `list<T const *>&`. Now consider the following code:

```
list<char*> a;
list<char const*>& b = a;

b.push_back("foo");

a.front()[0] = 'x'; // oops mutating const data
```

It's the same conceptual problem with converting `T**` to `T const**`.

If you want to provide readonly access to the underlying data, you will need to provide some custom view of it, possibly using custom iterators.

Something like the following.

```
template <typename It>
class const_const_iterator {
private:
    using underlying_value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;

    static_assert(std::is_pointer<underlying_value_type>(),
                  "must be an iterator to a pointer");

    using pointerless_value_type = typename std::remove_pointer<underlying_value_type>::type;

public:
    const_const_iterator(It it) : it(it) {}

    using value_type = pointerless_value_type const*;

    value_type operator*() const {
        return *it; // *it is a T*, but we return a T const*,
                    // converted implicitly
                    // also note that it is not assignable
    }

    // rest of iterator implementation here
    // boost::iterator_facade may be of help

private:
    It it;
};

template <typename Container>
class const_const_view {
private:
    using container_iterator = typename Container::iterator;

public:
    using const_iterator = const_const_iterator<container_iterator>;
    using iterator = const_iterator;

    const_const_view(Container const& container) : container(&container) {}

    const_iterator begin() const { return iterator(container->begin()); }
    const_iterator end() const { return iterator(container->end()); }

private:
    Container const* container;
}
```

Comment: Wow... several new things to me in your solution: using [name] = typename T and static_assert... what version of the standard does this need?  (I've been away from C++ for a while)

Comment: They are from C++11. `using A = B;` is the same as `typedef B A;`; since it's merely a stylistic matter you can replace it with typedef. `static_assert` causes a compilation error if the condition is not met. It isn't truly necessary for the solution, but it helps because it provides a better error message. You can leave it out too. `std::remove_pointer` is also from C++11, but it can easily be implemented without C++11 (https://gist.github.com/rmartinho/5142454).

Comment: The ideal solution would 'compile away', producing the same assembly code as const-less code.  This solution must use more memory because there is a new class of non-zero size.  Indirections could potentially be optimized away - depends whether `It::operator*` can be inlined... Could `const_const_iterator` be privately derived from `It` to remove levels of indirection and extra memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

Don't return containers. Return iterators.

Comment: @nsgulliver - if your only tool is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. It's usually better to answer the **right** question than to blindly answer the one that was asked.

Comment: you are absolutely right! however it can be great to have little bit more detail to motivate the answer. – nsgulliver 4 mins ago

Comment: The motivation for returning something more than iterators is that the container might have other useful functionality like `size()`, `operator[]`, `front()` etc.  It's a pain to have to write boilerplate code to patch them all through.  As well as being tedious to write,  a class's true purpose quickly becomes obscured in an ocean of trivialities.